# MongoDB with java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson

Tags: java, mongodb, jar, executable-jar, bson

When I execute mycode from intelliJ Idea it works fine but when I run the jar on my server it throws the below error. I am using  'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.1' version.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson
        at com.myapp.server.mongo.MongoDbHandler.prepareMongoDb(MongoDbHandler.java:68)
        at com.myapp.server.mongo.MongoDbHandler.<init>(MongoDbHandler.java:22)
        at com.myapp.server.Client.main(Client.java:167)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Could you please add more information?
Are you referring to a web server or an application server or your mongo server? 
What Java version you are using? Is it a maven build?
Do you have the same Java version on the server as on your intelliJ Idea?

Comment: Most probably a dependency issue. 
Would make sense to post a part of your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, or `ivy.xml`, or wherever you define the dependencies.

Comment: i am using build.gradle with server java 1.8 version and intellij with 1.7 java version

Comment: put " compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'bson', version: '2.5.1' " under dependancies in your gradle build file; sounds like that'll fix you up

Comment: @Hans i just tried with your solution with bson version 2.5.1 but getting error as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson

Comment: @Swapnil you can use any version you like, that just happens to be the one I found, usually to change which version gradle resolves for you, all you need to do is change 2.5.1 with x.y.z where x.y.z is your version number

Comment: @Hans i tried with recent version 3.4.0 also still getting same error

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old thread and its just for those who have the similar issues. Few days back I was also facing the same issue with same error trace while running the jar by command line.After rechecking the code found that

> It was not a problem of the jar version but its problem of the packaging of the
>   jar

After packing the jar with all proper dependencies will solve this issue.

I have used

> maven-assembly-plugin

for packaging and its works.

.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess you need to get yourself whatever BSON library you're using; I wouldn't say that Mongo is your problem.

key line here is:
"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson"

So it's saying that it's not finding that particular class, I would look in IntelliJ and see what BSON library it is, then put it in your build directory (or java lib) on your server.

Comment: i tried this solution earlier with different version of bson library but i am getting same result. i have updated my mongo library from 2.10.0 to 3.4.0 then i am facing this issue

Comment: you shouldn't have to change the version, it's probably a case of not being in the directory you/java think it should be. The easiest way to check would be to put it in the same directory as your jar and import <insert file name here of bson library> (ie import bson3.2.1; exclude the file extension) that should let you see if it's a path issue.

Comment: but from 2.10.0 version few methods are get deprecated  so i updated with recent version 3.4.0