# Cannot connect to MongoDb with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Im trying to use Morphia to read from a MongoDb.Im using Mongo v3.6.4. I've added the Morphia dependancy:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now I try to connect to my MongoDb:

```
final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.mapPackage("org.mongodb.morphia.example");
final Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient("localhost", 27017), "redmatter");
```

But I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/conversions/Bson
    at org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia.createDatastore(Morphia.java:90)
    at com.ie.pereda.server.GraphHandler.handle(GraphHandler.java:44)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.conversions.Bson
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have no issues connecting to the same Mondo database when I do:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"));
DB database = mongoClient.getDB("redmatter");
```

That connects no problem. What could the issue with Morphia be?

**EDIT**

@Victor's solution appears to have fixed this problem, but presented a new one:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClient.getDatabase(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase;
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.<init>(DatastoreImpl.java:114)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.<init>(DatastoreImpl.java:99)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia.createDatastore(Morphia.java:90)
    at com.ie.pereda.server.GraphHandler.handle(GraphHandler.java:44)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Mongo is definitely running as my previous code for connecting works...

Comment: I believe it is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912639/mongodb-with-java-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Ok, This looks like wrong versions. Please list all your dependencies.

Comment: post your full pom.xml please. are you declaring an explicit dep on the driver?  looks like a version mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, that got passed that problem but now there's a new problem, will update question